# Google Apps Script Add-Ons not update deployments after make change

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to update Add-Ons deployment after make change to code and publish(private) to Google Workspace Marketplace. But, it seems like the Add-Ons didn't update the Add-Ons.

After I click on [Deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FINbl.png) it didn't update the Add-Ons, I know this because, when I run from [Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olWQl.png) (Sheets with Add-Ons script) code and this [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eFei.png) from Another sheets where Add-Ons is installed, That **v1.0** is not showing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When making a change to an Add-on published on Marketplace, use [Versioned deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#versioned_deployments).
- This means, every time you would like to update the published version, the best approach would to create a [new deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#create_a_versioned_deployment).

[image]

- After creating a new deployment, you need to change the `Deployment ID` accordingly in Marketplace `APP CONFIGURATION`.

[image]

- Do not forget to press the "SAVE" button at the bottom of `APP CONFIGURATION`.

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings that are not well documented and made my life harder. Sharing here as someone might also be struggling when updating a published Google Workspace Add-on (not to be confused with an [Editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types)).

I found this in a google-apps-script-community [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/yC6EhulsPWc):

> ...people have had issues when they kept creating new Deployments instead
> of editing existing deployments. Did you choose "New deployment" or
> "Manage deployments"
>
> New editor using Manage Deployments, and then clicking the pen and
> creating a new version, works fine. Don't click the New deployment, as
> that will starta new branch that has no real connection with the
> already deployed branch.

What ended up working for me:

- In the apps script editor in Deploy -> Manage Deployments find the deployment that has the same deployment_id that you specified when you first published the add-on to the marketplace. To find it go to the respective GCP project and navigate to Enabled API Services -> Google Workspace Marketplace SDK -> APP CONFIGURATION -> App Integration -> Deployment Id.
- Once you have identified the apps script deployment from the step above click the pen (edit) and choose new version in the Version drop-down and hit the Deploy button.
- That's it.